# LINQ to SQL - Insert Custom Raw SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to insert custom raw sql with linq (or some linq extension like DynamicLinq). And if not, how would this be possible?

This would be helpful with DocumentDB. Here is an example of what I mean.

```
class Document {
  Guid id { get; set; }
  DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
  DocumentType type { get; set; }
  dynamic content { get; set; }
}

queryable
  .Where((d) => d.type == DocumentType.IceCream)
  .RawSqlWhere("CONTAINS(content.flavor, 'choco')")
  .Where((d) => d.createdAt < DateTime.Now);
```

If Linq isn't right for this, how would you go about doing this without losing linq support?

Comment: I would look into Dapper.  DapperExtensions will also give you the ability to use Linq with DTOs. https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions

Comment: Uinsg SQL Server, you can mix LINQ (with expressions) and Dynamic LINQ. SInce Dynamic LINQ does nothing but parsing strings to expressions, I'd expect this should work for any SQL provider that accepts expressions.

Comment: I guess the main issue is that CONTAINS is an sql function and my documents are so dynamic they can't be deserialized. so that's why I was hoping to just inject sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DocumentDB LINQ provider supports Dynamic LINQ. You can use that to build runtime LINQ expressions. Injecting SQL is not currently supported.